# Update Drawercontent with userdata and handle data after Login in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i played around react native and one problem comes in every screen. Access Userdata.
After Login the userdata is saved in Asyncstorage so i can access this data in every screen. This solution is slow and laborious.

But step by step. First i have my rootnavigator see below:

```
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} theme={navigationTheme}>
  <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent  user={user} {...props} />}>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStackNavigator}  initialParams={{ user : user }}/>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={StackNavigator}   initialParams={{ user : user }}/>
  </Drawer.Navigator> 
</NavigationContainer>
```

First the AuthStack is loaded where a loading screen check if asyncstorage userdata (and other things) is saved. If its saved its redirect to StackNavigator -> Home. If not, LoginScreen is showing.
it works es expected.

As you can imagine, after login the parent Drawercontent isnt updated, because its not unmounted before.

I dont really like this solution so my questions are:

1. is it possible to update Drawercontent?
2. is there a much better way to handle userdata?
   Redux is available but i have read that redux isnt the best solution for this too?!
   Firebase is also available, so that is used maybe?

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar challenge on my last react native project in which I've used redux and Firebase and in my experience it worked very well, similar to you  have a navigator stack as the parent stack, and the `initialRouteName` is AUTHORIZER which navigates to screen that dispatches a redux action that checks for Authentication status using firebase but in your case it could be asyncstorage so if the the user is logged I navigate from that action the the appropriate screen , also it updates redux state specify the Auth reducer's `isAuthtinticated`  which then can be accessed from screen within the stacks that are nested in `drawerNavigator`  :

App.js

```
import { Provider} from 'react-redux'
const App= () => {

return <Provider store={store}> 
         <Navigator/> 
 </Provider>
}
```

Navigator

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Navigator =()=>{
    return <NavigationContainer >
       <Drawer.Navigator 
       screenOptions={{headerShown:false}} 
       initialRouteName="AUTHORIZER"
       drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
       >
             <Drawer.Screen name="ADMINDashBoard"  component={AdminStackNavigator} />
             <Drawer.Screen name="DISTRUBUTORDashBoard" component={DistributorStackNavigator} />
             <Drawer.Screen name="LOGIN" component={Login} />
             <Drawer.Screen name="REGISTER" component={Register} />
             <Drawer.Screen name="AUTHORIZER" component={Authorizer} />
       </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
}
```

Authorizer component

```
const  Authorizer=({navigation,checkAuthetication})=> {

    useEffect(() => {
      
            setTimeout(() => {
                   checkAuthetication({navigation})
            }, 2000);
     
    }, [])

 
  /.. rest of component
}
```

checkAuthetication action

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default async (args,state,dispatch)=>{
    try {
        const {navigation}= args //here I'm passing navigation from Authorizer component from which this action is called

       auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user=>{
            let savePassword  = await AsyncStorage.getItem('SAVE_PASSWORD')
            savePassword = JSON.stringify(savePassword)
            const savedPassword  = await AsyncStorage.getItem('PASSWORD')
            const savedEmail  = await AsyncStorage.getItem('EMAIL')
          
            if(user){      
                   //get user doc from async storage
                
                    let userDoc
                    let userType
 
                    const userDocResponse =await firestore().collection('users').where('user_id','==',user.uid)

                    userDocResponse.onSnapshot(res=>{
                        const docs=res.docs
                        userDoc={...docs[0].data(),id:docs[0].id}
                        userType=docs[0].data().type

                        console.log('try getting user doc ' )
                        dispatch.auth.checkedAuthentication({
                            authenticated:true,
                            user:userDoc,
                            userType 
                        })

                       if(userType != null){
                           //check if user in approved by admin if not then we redirect them to waitingRoom 
                           if(userDoc != undefined && userDoc.confirmed =="PENDING") 
                              return navigation.navigate("WAIT_ROOM") 
  
                           //redirect logged users that are approved to their appropriate Dashboard
                           if(userDoc != undefined){ 
                              return  navigation.navigate(userType+'DashBoard')
                           }
                       }
                    })            
            }else{ 
                 //this means no user is authenticated so we should navigate to Login screen
                 dispatch.auth.checkedAuthentication({
                     authenticated : false,
                     user          : null,
                     userType      : null,
                  })
                 navigation.navigate('LOGIN')
            }
       })
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("\n-------HECKOUT AUTH ERROR ----------")
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```